# Faster way to do this comparison of string in perl for foreign charsets

Tags: perl

I have the following code which works well:

```
foreach my $type (qw/Arabic Armenian Bengali Bopomofo Braille Buhid Canadian_Aboriginal Cherokee Cyrillic Devanagari Ethiopic Georgian Greek Gujarati Gurmukhi Han Hangul Hanunoo Hebrew Hiragana Kannada Katakana Khmer Lao Limbu Malayalam Mongolian Myanmar Ogham Oriya Runic Sinhala Syriac Tagalog Tagbanwa TaiLe Tamil Telugu Thaana Thai Tibetan/) {
    if ($page_title =~ /\p{Script_Extensions=$type}/i) {

        print qq|TITLE: $_->{domain} is not english ($type), so lets ignore it...\n| if $DEBUG > 0;

        last;
    }
}
```

All it does is look for certain charsets, so we can get rid of those we don't want. Now while it works, its a bit slow (as its doing a `foreach()` on each one). Is there a way to this in the single regex? (and also extract the matching set if possible)

**UPDATE:** I'm now trying as suggested with:

```
if ($page_title =~ /\p{Script_Extensions=Han|Arabic|Armenian|Bengali|Bopomofo|Braille|Buhid|Canadian_Aboriginal|Cherokee|Cyrillic|Devanagari|Ethiopic|Georgian|Greek|Gujarati|Gurmukhi|Hangul|Hanunoo|Hebrew|Hiragana|Kannada|Katakana|Khmer|Lao|Limbu|Malayalam|Mongolian|Myanmar|Ogham|Oriya|Runic|Sinhala|Syriac|Tagalog|Tagbanwa|TaiLe|Tamil|Telugu|Thaana|Thai|Tibetan}/i) {
    colored(qq|$page_title matches $1, so lets ignore... |, 'yellow on_magenta'), "\n";
}
```

and also:

```
if ($page_title =~ /\p{Script_Extensions=(Han|Arabic|Armenian|Bengali|Bopomofo|Braille|Buhid|Canadian_Aboriginal|Cherokee|Cyrillic|Devanagari|Ethiopic|Georgian|Greek|Gujarati|Gurmukhi|Hangul|Hanunoo|Hebrew|Hiragana|Kannada|Katakana|Khmer|Lao|Limbu|Malayalam|Mongolian|Myanmar|Ogham|Oriya|Runic|Sinhala|Syriac|Tagalog|Tagbanwa|TaiLe|Tamil|Telugu|Thaana|Thai|Tibetan)}/i) {
    colored(qq|$page_title matches $1, so lets ignore... |, 'yellow on_magenta'), "\n";
}
```

But I get an error:

> Can't find Unicode property definition
> "Script_Extensions=Han|Arabic|Armenian|Bengali|Bopomofo|Braille|Buhid|Canadian_Aboriginal|Cherokee|Cyrillic|Devanagari|Ethiopic|Georgian|Greek|Gujarati|Gurmukhi|Hangul|Hanunoo|Hebrew|Hiragana|Kannada|Katakana|Khmer|Lao|Limbu|Malayalam|Mongolian|Myanmar|Ogham|Oriya|Runic|Sinhala|Syriac|Tagalog|Tagbanwa|TaiLe|Tamil|Telugu|Thaana|Thai|Tibetan"
> in regex; marked by <-- HERE in
> m/\p{Script_Extensions=Han|Arabic|Armenian|Bengali|Bopomofo|Braille|Buhid|Canadian_Aboriginal|Che
> at process-all-domains.cgi line 300.

Comment: A look-up table would be faster than a linear scan each time.

Comment: @tadman not sure what you mean?

Comment: Use a hash like `%languages = { Arabic => true, ... }` and then you can quickly test with `$languages{$type}` for example. I'd scan for the `Script_Exensions=(\S+)` part and then test for that in the hash.

Comment: You could also mash those together into a singular regular expression like `(Arabic|Armenian|...)` to test for them all at once.

Comment: Ah ok - so `if ($page_title =~ /\p{Script_Extensions=(Han|Arabic|Armenian|Bengali|Bopomofo|Braille)}/i) {` would work, and then store the matching set name to `$1`?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. If you're expecting a list of those, or multiple matches you'll have to tweak it. If you can get that working, worth writing up as a self-answer.

Comment: @tadman sweet - thanks (I wasn't aware you could pass in multiple values). Just testing it out now and will then write up an answer. Appreciate the help :)

Comment: Oh, you can use a regular expression for all sorts of things, and if you've seen enough Perl you'll see it used for things you didn't even think possible, like [detecting prime numbers](https://catonmat.net/perl-regex-that-matches-prime-numbers).

Comment: @tadman hmm doesn't seem to like it? `Can't find Unicode property definition "Script_Extensions=(Han|Arabic|Armenian|Bengali|Bopomofo|Braille|Buhid|Canadian_Aboriginal|Cherokee|Cyrillic|Devanagari|Ethiopic|Georgian|Greek|Gujarati|Gurmukhi|Hangul|Hanunoo|Hebrew|Hiragana|Kannada|Katakana|Khmer|Lao|Limbu|Malayalam|Mongolian|Myanmar|Ogham|Oriya|Runic|Sinhala|Syriac|Tagalog|Tagbanwa|TaiLe|Tamil|Telugu|Thaana|Thai|Tibetan)" in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/\p{Script_Extensions=(Han|Arabic|Armenian|Bengali|Bopomofo|Braille|Buhid|Canadian_Aboriginal| at process-all-domains.cgi`

Comment: You may need to edit your question with the updated problem. That looks different from your code.

Comment: Do you mean to match literal `\p` or are you using the `\p` feature of the regex? If so I see what you're trying to do now, and that may be a different problem.

Comment: @tadman hmm I'm not sure. I just want to match it against the string I have to see if it contains any of those sets.

Comment: It may be easier to detect non-ASCII characters than to enumerate every possible language that's not English.

Comment: @tadman but wouldn't that also match utf-8 stuff like "long -" ?

Comment: That, emoji, mathematical symbols. If you want to get real fussy here you could look at the various [code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) and pick which you want to permit. It could be [quite an adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page), especially with how people tend to appropriate Inuktitut and Japanese for various emoticons like ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ and (ง’̀-‘́)ง.

Comment: @tadman haha yeah, thats the problem. I don't want to over-kill. Basically I'm using this method to weed out non-english sites (crazy how many Chinese Han sites there are even on .co.uk!). Also I'm only really worried about business sites - so I don't think people would use ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ kinda stuff on there, but I could be wrong :) I'll keep playing with the regex and see if I can come up with something

Comment: This sounds more like a job for machine learning or a quick sniff-test of the distribution of characters in the text. If 90+% of them are ASCII it's *probably* a Latin language. The rest requires statistical tables and such. Each language has a fairly distinct skew towards which words are used most frequently. If you had lots of hits in the top 1000 English words plus it's 95% ASCII it's almost certainly English.

Comment: @tadman yeah its a bit of a bugger. Interestingly, removing the `\p` seems to have got rid of the error. Just running it through now to see if it still picks up the matches compared to the old code - so `if ($page_title =~ /{Script_Extensions=(Han|Arabic|Armenian|Bengali|Bopomofo|Braille|Buhid|Canadian_Aboriginal|Cherokee|Cyrillic|Devanagari|Ethiopic|Georgian|Greek|Gujarati|Gurmukhi|Hangul|Hanunoo|Hebrew|Hiragana|Kannada|Katakana|Khmer|Lao|Limbu|Malayalam|Mongolian|Myanmar|Ogham|Oriya|Runic|Sinhala|Syriac|Tagalog|Tagbanwa|TaiLe|Tamil|Telugu|Thaana|Thai|Tibetan)}/i) {`

Comment: Do also check the site headers to see if the content is tagged with a particular language either in the HTTP response or the `<meta>` section of the `<head>` or the `<html>` tag itself. Maybe all the information you need is already there. For example, qq.com has `<html lang="zh-CN">` which is super helpful.

Comment: Yup - using `\<meta.*?http-equiv\=\"Content-Language\" content=\"([a-z]{2})\".*?\>` to get the content-language var, and also `\<html.*?lang=\"([a-z]{2})([-_][A-Z]{2})?\".*?\>` to get the language var (not perfect, but seems to do the job on 99%)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I'm guessing there's no point in using `/i`.

As for solution, alternation is an option.

```perl
/
     \p{Script_Extensions=Arabic}
   | \p{Script_Extensions=Armenian}
   | \p{Script_Extensions=Bengali}
   | ...
   | \p{Script_Extensions=Thaana}
   | \p{Script_Extensions=Thai}
   | \p{Script_Extensions=Tibetan}
/x
```

Alternation allows us to use whitespace, but a faster solution would be a character class.

```perl
/
   [\p{Script_Extensions=Arabic}\p{Script_Extensions=Armenian}\p{Script_Extensions=Bengali}...\p{Script_Extensions=Thaana}\p{Script_Extensions=Thai}\p{Script_Extensions=Tibetan}]
/x
```

However, just 3 of the 41 properties takes up the entire width of the screen.  As with the other solutions presented here, nothing stops you from building the pattern dynamically.

```perl
my $class_body =
   join '',
      map "\\p{Script_Extensions=$_}",
         qw(
            Arabic Armenian Bengali
            ...
            Thaana Thai Tibetan
         );

/[$class_body]/
```

But there's an alternative: `(?[...])`

```perl
/
   (?[ \p{Script_Extensions=Arabic}
   +   \p{Script_Extensions=Armenian}
   +   \p{Script_Extensions=Bengali}
   +   ...
   +   \p{Script_Extensions=Thaana}
   +   \p{Script_Extensions=Thai}
   +   \p{Script_Extensions=Tibetan}
   ])
/x
```

This requires `use experimental qw( regex_sets );` before 5.36. But it's safe to add this and use the feature as far back as its introduction as an experimental feature in 5.18, since no change was made to the feature since then.

Comment: Oh I like the suggestion of using the character class- much cleaner. And also map to build up the regex. Doing a benchmark on those 2 comes up good: my new method: `test1: 105 wallclock secs (92.75 usr +  0.06 sys = 92.81 CPU) @ 107747.01/s (n=10000000)` - char class method: `test2: 23 wallclock secs (10.76 usr +  0.07 sys = 10.83 CPU) @ 923361.03/s (n=10000000)`

Comment: and also, good shout about `/i`  - but sure why I put that on there as it makes bugger all difference when looking at whole sets!

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could seem to get it to work, was with:

```
if ($page_title =~ /\p{Script_Extensions=Han}|\p{Script_Extensions=Arabic}|\p{Script_Extensions=Armenian}|\p{Script_Extensions=Bengali}|\p{Script_Extensions=Bopomofo}|\p{Script_Extensions=Braille}|\p{Script_Extensions=Buhid}|\p{Script_Extensions=Canadian_Aboriginal}|\p{Script_Extensions=Cherokee}|\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}|\p{Script_Extensions=Devanagari}|\p{Script_Extensions=Ethiopic}|\p{Script_Extensions=Georgian}|\p{Script_Extensions=Greek}|\p{Script_Extensions=Gujarati}|\p{Script_Extensions=Gurmukhi}|\p{Script_Extensions=Hangul}|\p{Script_Extensions=Hanunoo}|\p{Script_Extensions=Hebrew}|\p{Script_Extensions=Hiragana}|\p{Script_Extensions=Kannada}|\p{Script_Extensions=Katakana}|\p{Script_Extensions=Khmer}|\p{Script_Extensions=Lao}|\p{Script_Extensions=Limbu}|\p{Script_Extensions=Malayalam}|\p{Script_Extensions=Mongolian}|\p{Script_Extensions=Myanmar}|\p{Script_Extensions=Ogham}|\p{Script_Extensions=Oriya}|\p{Script_Extensions=Runic}|\p{Script_Extensions=Sinhala}|\p{Script_Extensions=Syriac}|\p{Script_Extensions=Tagalog}|\p{Script_Extensions=Tagbanwa}|\p{Script_Extensions=TaiLe}|\p{Script_Extensions=Tamil}|\p{Script_Extensions=Telugu}|\p{Script_Extensions=Thaana}|\p{Script_Extensions=Thai}|\p{Script_Extensions=Tibetan}/i) {
    # ... match
}
```

Its a bit messy, but as far as I can see it's working.

An example of the benchmarking:

```
  use Benchmark;

  my $page = Common::get_html_file("bsscn2p.com","home");

  my $page_title;
  if ($page =~ /\<title\>(.+?)\<\/title\>/i) {
    $page_title = $1;
  }

  timethese(100000, {
    test1 => sub {
      if ($page_title =~ /\p{Script_Extensions=Han}|\p{Script_Extensions=Arabic}|\p{Script_Extensions=Armenian}|\p{Script_Extensions=Bengali}|\p{Script_Extensions=Bopomofo}|\p{Script_Extensions=Braille}|\p{Script_Extensions=Buhid}|\p{Script_Extensions=Canadian_Aboriginal}|\p{Script_Extensions=Cherokee}|\p{Script_Extensions=Cyrillic}|\p{Script_Extensions=Devanagari}|\p{Script_Extensions=Ethiopic}|\p{Script_Extensions=Georgian}|\p{Script_Extensions=Greek}|\p{Script_Extensions=Gujarati}|\p{Script_Extensions=Gurmukhi}|\p{Script_Extensions=Hangul}|\p{Script_Extensions=Hanunoo}|\p{Script_Extensions=Hebrew}|\p{Script_Extensions=Hiragana}|\p{Script_Extensions=Kannada}|\p{Script_Extensions=Katakana}|\p{Script_Extensions=Khmer}|\p{Script_Extensions=Lao}|\p{Script_Extensions=Limbu}|\p{Script_Extensions=Malayalam}|\p{Script_Extensions=Mongolian}|\p{Script_Extensions=Myanmar}|\p{Script_Extensions=Ogham}|\p{Script_Extensions=Oriya}|\p{Script_Extensions=Runic}|\p{Script_Extensions=Sinhala}|\p{Script_Extensions=Syriac}|\p{Script_Extensions=Tagalog}|\p{Script_Extensions=Tagbanwa}|\p{Script_Extensions=TaiLe}|\p{Script_Extensions=Tamil}|\p{Script_Extensions=Telugu}|\p{Script_Extensions=Thaana}|\p{Script_Extensions=Thai}|\p{Script_Extensions=Tibetan}/i) {
        #print qq|TITLE: $page_title matches, so lets ignore... $_->{domain} \n|;
      }
    },
    test2 => sub {

      foreach my $type (qw/Han Arabic Armenian Bengali Bopomofo Braille Buhid Canadian_Aboriginal Cherokee Cyrillic Devanagari Ethiopic Georgian Greek Gujarati Gurmukhi Hangul Hanunoo Hebrew Hiragana Kannada Katakana Khmer Lao Limbu Malayalam Mongolian Myanmar Ogham Oriya Runic Sinhala Syriac Tagalog Tagbanwa TaiLe Tamil Telugu Thaana Thai Tibetan/) {
          if ($page_title =~ /\p{Script_Extensions=$type}/i) {
            #print "MATCH for $type! \n";
          }
      }

    }
  });


Benchmark: timing 100000 iterations of test1, test2...
     test1:  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.03 CPU) @ 3333333.33/s (n=100000)
            (warning: too few iterations for a reliable count)
     test2: 117 wallclock secs (115.36 usr +  0.13 sys = 115.49 CPU) @ 865.88/s (n=100000)
```

So quite a lot better and more efficient with the new code :)

Comment: Maybe build that regexp at runtime from OP's original list of scripts?